# How to make footnotes in parcolumns?

Tags: footnotes, parcolumns

I need to have two columns of text that span over multiple pages placed next to each other, which I managed to do using parcolumns. However, when I try to insert a footnote, it's content doesn't show at the end of the page. Also, the footnote count inside the parcolumns starts with 1, however, I need it to continue the count of my previous footnotes in the text (e.g. if I already have 3 footnotes in my text, the footnote in the parcolumns should continue with 4).
Is there a possibility to do this?

```
\documentclass{article} 

\usepackage{setspace}
\onehalfspacing
\usepackage{parcolumns}

\begin{document}

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed sem ligula, finibus non nulla et, viverra interdum enim. Vivamus suscipit, risus a pretium finibus, risus tellus congue tortor, id tincidunt ipsum nunc nec nibh. Aliquam erat volutpat. Donec vel ligula a arcu pharetra tempor non ac metus. Ut vehicula tortor eu purus euismod, et pretium orci commodo. Cras lobortis lobortis magna et semper. Ut ut metus eu elit\footnote{lorem impsum} euismod dapibus a et odio. Sed eleifend, urna at sodales sodales, massa lacus tristique eros, sit amet suscipit felis augue eu enim. Aenean blandit elit sed lacus aliquam imperdiet. Nullam id hendrerit ligula. Aenean finibus ligula in fermentum aliquet. 

\begin{parcolumns}{2}
\colchunk[1]{%
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed sem ligula, finibus non nulla et, viverra interdum enim. Vivamus suscipit, risus a pretium finibus, risus tellus congue tortor, id tincidunt ipsum nunc nec nibh. Aliquam erat volutpat. Donec vel ligula a arcu pharetra tempor non ac metus. 
Ut vehicula tortor eu purus euismod, et pretium orci commodo. Cras lobortis lobortis magna et semper. Ut ut metus eu elit\footnote{lorem impsum} euismod dapibus a et odio. 
Sed eleifend, urna at sodales sodales, massa lacus tristique eros, sit amet suscipit felis augue eu enim. Aenean blandit elit sed lacus aliquam imperdiet. Nullam id hendrerit ligula. Aenean finibus ligula in fermentum aliquet.
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed sem ligula, finibus non nulla et, viverra interdum enim. Vivamus suscipit, risus a pretium finibus, risus tellus congue tortor, id tincidunt ipsum nunc nec nibh. Aliquam erat volutpat. Donec vel ligula a arcu pharetra tempor non ac metus. Ut vehicula tortor eu purus euismod, et pretium orci commodo. Cras lobortis lobortis magna et semper. 
Ut ut metus eu elit euismod dapibus a et odio. Sed eleifend, urna at sodales sodales, massa lacus tristique eros, sit amet suscipit felis augue eu enim. 
Aenean blandit elit sed lacus aliquam imperdiet. Nullam id hendrerit ligula. Aenean finibus ligula in fermentum aliquet.
}
\colchunk[2]{%
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed sem ligula, finibus non nulla et, viverra interdum enim. Vivamus suscipit, risus a pretium finibus, risus tellus congue tortor, id tincidunt ipsum nunc nec nibh. Aliquam erat volutpat. Donec vel ligula a arcu pharetra tempor non ac metus. Ut vehicula tortor eu purus euismod, et pretium orci commodo. Cras lobortis lobortis magna et semper. 
Ut ut metus eu elit euismod dapibus a et odio. Sed eleifend, urna at sodales sodales, massa lacus tristique eros, sit amet suscipit felis augue eu enim. 
Aenean blandit elit sed lacus aliquam imperdiet. Nullam id hendrerit ligula. Aenean finibus ligula in fermentum aliquet.
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed sem ligula, finibus non nulla et, viverra interdum enim. Vivamus suscipit, risus a pretium finibus, risus tellus congue tortor, id tincidunt ipsum nunc nec nibh. Aliquam erat volutpat. Donec vel ligula a arcu pharetra tempor non ac metus. Ut vehicula tortor eu purus euismod, et pretium orci commodo. Cras lobortis lobortis magna et semper. 
Ut ut metus eu elit euismod dapibus a et odio. Sed eleifend, urna at sodales sodales, massa lacus tristique eros, sit amet suscipit felis augue eu enim. 
Aenean blandit elit sed lacus aliquam imperdiet. Nullam id hendrerit ligula. Aenean finibus ligula in fermentum aliquet.
}
\end{parcolumns}

\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: @Rmano is this more clear now?

Comment: Yes, but `UniVieCS_Thesis` is not a standard class. Can you reproduce the problem with, say, `article`?

Comment: @rmano oh yeah sorry, fixed it now

Comment: And your question is still open? I.e. footnotes don't behave as you'd like to?

Comment: @MS-SPO yes, I can confirm, `footnote` is acting up inside the parcolumns

Comment: @rmano yes, the problem with footnotes not showing is still not solved